# print all records of all tables in oracle database

Tags: relational-database, sqlplus

How do I create a query that prints all records from all tables using SQL*Plus?

I can retrieve all tables using this:

```
select object_name from all_objects
where owner='me' and object_type='TABLE'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name
FROM user_tab_cols
WHERE table_name in (SELECT table_name  FROM dba_tables)
```

Comment: 1  SELECT column_name
         2  FROM user_tab_cols
         3  WHERE table_name in (SELECT object_name as table_name
         4   FROM all_objects
         5* where owner='me' and object_type='TABLE')
returns only attribute names, i want the records. i.e. tuples